# I'm encountering a mirror pose problem. The left hand is supposed to take the right hand's exact pose but it ends up looking different. Why is this?

Tags: rigging, pose-mode

The left hand ends up getting that weird pose that doesn't look exactly like the right hand after I copied and pasted the right hand's pose to the left hand. It's really annoying. How do I fix this?
Here's my file:

[image]

[image: mirror pose hand]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe the bones of the left hand don't have the correct orientation, check or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

- In edit mode, enable x-axis mirror.

[image]

If you don't see this tool bar, click View ⇾ Tool Settings.

- Then select bones from one hand and press <kbd>G</kbd>. Apply this without moving. This should symmetrize the bones.
- You can also use x-axis mirror in pose mode

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: I've updated the answer